# Functionality like MS Word

Tags: asp.net

Is there any control available like MS word in asp.net or using any other third party component. I tried rad text editor but it's not supporting page break. so please let me know if there's any control available for my purpose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is almost certainly going to be closed because asking questions recommending tools are off topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask your best bet is to look at some of the javascript libraries which convert textareas to rich text editors

Comment: Well what about support for Header and Footer on each page like Word ;)

Comment: I was also once looking for a text editor which could retain the word content as much as possible in editor and find RadEditor best. But didn't find any was to maintain the page break.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with a predecessor of this one I think it was called FCKEditor back then. It has loads of configuration possibilities and seems to do the job you want to have done:

http://ckeditor.com/

EDIT: seems like the support for page breaks is not out of the box, but it can be added:
http://ckeditor.com/addon/pagebreak

Comment: does it have support for page break?

Comment: @KamranShahid I mentioned that in my edit

Comment: ok. I think i have read your unedited post.Also I have just tried to copy my sample content in there editor and it is loosing lots of formatting. [While Rad Editor maintains it]

Comment: @KamranShahid seems one has to set the appropriate flags in `config.js` so that formatting is maintained http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9273

Answer (score 0):

The best rich text editor is **TinyMce**.

See [here](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php).